# How to use Apply and Map properly in this situation?

Tags: list-manipulation, function-construction

So this does what I want:

```
#1 <> #2 &["♠", "A"]

♠A
```

The output is fine. How do I quickly apply this to the list

```
{{"♠", "A"}, {"♢", "A"}, {"♣", "A"}, {"♡", "A"}}
```

So that I can combined all of the suits with the Aces?
I have tried a mixture of "/", "@" and "/@". None of these worked.

[image]

Comment: You want `@@@` -- apply at level 1.

Comment: @jjc385 THANKS! Finally, I got it! `(#1 <> ToString[#2] &) @@@ carddeck`

Comment: Happy to help.  Note that if `carddeck` is a nested list like the list given in the question (with all sublist elements being strings), you shouldn't need the `ToString` in there.

Answer (score 4):

You want to [`Apply`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html) your function at level 1 in the list :

```
#1 <> #2 & @@@ {{"♠", "A"}, {"♢", "A"}, {"♣", "A"}, {"♡", "A"}}
```

> ```
> {"♠A", "♢A", "♣A", "♡A"}
> ```

As mentioned at the very top of the docs for `Apply`, `f @@@ expr` is is syntactic sugar for `Apply[ f, expr, {1} ]`, and has the same effect as `Apply[ f, # ]& /@ expr`.

---

Note that `#1 <> #2 &` parses as `StringJoin[#1,#2]&`, for which you might as well just use `StringJoin` :

```
StringJoin @@@ {{"♠", "A"}, {"♢", "A"}, {"♣", "A"}, {"♡", "A"}}
```

> ```
> {"♠A", "♢A", "♣A", "♡A"}
> ```